# Regarding the usage of future perfect tense

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

Can we use "would" instead of "will" in the future perfect tense?

Please explain it and give some examples.

Comment: If we said *"I would have gone"* instead of *"I will have gone"*, would it still be the "future perfect tense"? Your question is not clear. It would be greatly improved by examples.

Comment: There isn't any future tense in English, so there isn't any future perfect tense, either. _Will_ is just another modal auxiliary verb, like _would, may, might, shall, should, can, could,_ and _must_. All of them can refer to future time, just like _will_, and all of them can occur with infinitives without _to_, just like _will_. So, yes, you can. Rest easy. But find a better grammar text. The one that gave you the false information you based your question on is not reliable. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnLawler English makes future tenses and others by adding auxiliary verbs.

Comment: @RShields There must be an awful lot of tenses in English, then, because there are an awful lot of auxiliary constructions. The [past tenses alone](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/tense.html#tenselist) can run into the dozens.

Comment: @JohnLawler Welcome to English conjugation. (I speak some Chinese on the side and lemme tell you, Chinese conjugation is a breeze!)

Answer (score 0):

The future perfect tense looks like

> I will have gone.

Changing "will" to "would" makes

> I would have gone.

which is actually **conditional perfect** tense.